# How can I use netstat to display only Protocol, Port and status?

Tags: grep, netstat

I am using `netstat -lt | grep LISTEN` to list all the tcp ports that are listening. I am supposed to use this data by my java application so I want to format the output in shell to reduce the processing overhead in Java. What I want is:

```
Protocol port status
tcp      4567 LISTEN
```

type of output. Is there any way to achieve this using netstat or is there any other network applications provided by unix to do this ?

I also tried reading the services files by:

```
less /etc/services | grep tcp | cut -d '#' -f 1
```

but that way it will list all the tcp ports even though they are open or not. Any suggestion would be great!

Comment: Do you care which IP it's listening on?  For example a computer might be listening on `0.0.0.0:4567` which is completely different from listening on `127.0.0.1:4567`

Comment: Actually I need this data for a client socket application, so yes the IP matters.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively read the file /proc/net/tcp rather than deal with the security issues of running a shell program.

Answer (score 1):

#### TLDR;

```
printf "Protocol port status";
netstat -nlt \
  |sed -e '/LISTEN/p;d' -e '1,2d' \
  |xargs -n6 \
  |cut -d\  -f1,4,6 \
  |sed 's/ .*:/ /';
```

#### Preamble

Going to address two things here particularly for future readers and web crawlers.

1. `/etc/services` is a "database" (e.g. flatfile cache) of IANA RFC 1340 Assigned Numbers for TCP and UDP ports. One uses this to translate the integer port number into logical string name or vice versa. There is a manual/documentation about this on every shell accessed with `man 5 services`.
2. Yes, if one is doing processing in a 'higher' level language like Java then `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` is not using the OS to its fullest. Better to read data from the `proc` and `sys` filesystems instead. Same goes for doing text processing outside of shell and `coreutils`.

That out of the way. To answer one's question first look at `sed`, `xargs`,
`cut`, and `expand`. `sed` is a stream editor with `regex`, `xargs` is equivalent to `map() with lambda` in other languages but also does line clean up, and expand strips whitespace characters to space. `netstat` also has a listen only output flag. These combined in a pipeline solves your need.

#### Breaking down the answer

| command | explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `printf` | same as C/C++'s printf() function [output the header] |
| `netstat -ntl` | parses `/proc/net/tcp` for bound listeners, without dns lookups |
| `sed -e '/LISTEN/p;d' -e '1,2d'` | Two pass sed in sequence: find all LISTEN records, delete all else, delete lines 1 AND 2 (the header from netstat; to prevent munging output) |
| `xargs -n6` | Format output as six columns of space deliminator records |
| `cut -d\ -f1,4,6` | use space deliminator then select columns 1, 4, and 6 |
| `sed 's/ .*:/ /'` | post process second column to strip IP address |

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't include the column headers but it gives you the data you want in a tab delimited format

```
netstat -lnt | tail -n+3 | awk '{print $1 "\t" $4 "\t" $6}'
```

Running on my computer I get the following output

```
tcp     127.0.0.1:3306  LISTEN
tcp     0.0.0.0:22      LISTEN
tcp6    :::22   LISTEN
```